# Is there a way to a @Published property that it's actually getting updated and publishing?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, combine

I have the following class, I want to test that if an object subscribed to "elapsedTime" published property, it will receive updates whenever the property changes.

```
class SampleSegmentTimer {
    @Published var elapsedTime: DateComponents?
    private var subs = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func start(tickingEvery interval: TimeInterval = 1) {
        Timer.publish(every: interval, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .map(transform)
            .assign(to: \.elapsedTime, on: self)
            .store(in: &subs)
    }

    private func transform(_ date: Date) -> DateComponents {
        // do some calculation
        DateComponents()
    }
}
```

I want to write test like the following:

```
func testStart() {
        // Given
        let segmentTimer = SampleSegmentTimer()
        var elapsedTimes = [DateComponents?]()
        let elapsedTimeSub = segmentTimer.$elapsedTime.sink { elapsedTimes.append($0) }

        // When
        segmentTimer.start(tickEvery: 1) // I want to wait 3 seconds to let it tick 3 times

        // Then
        XCTAssertEqual(elapsedTimes.count, 3)
}
```

Comment: First of all, it is pointless to test the Combine framework for what you already know it does. Second, it makes no sense to make a timer publisher and publish it to your own Published publisher. Two publishers? The Timer pipeline is already a publisher. Just put it where others can subscribe to it directly. Third, you have a retain cycle and memory leak, but never mind that now.

Comment: Also you do not need to map to measure elapsed time. There is an operator that measures intervals, or just use `scan` to maintain the interval or running total. It would be better to drop all your code and explain to us what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Apparently I didn't make my self clear. instead of responding to each point you've mentioned I'll try to explain what I'm actually working on or at least a simplified version. I want to build a timer app that allows the user to start a timer, keep running in the background, pause it, cancel it and end timer of course. when the timer ends the segment will be stored in core data among other attributes. the time segment (duration) should include the background time and exclude the paused durations if the user pauses and resumes many times.

Comment: OK. A pausable cancellable timer is a well-solved problem; you can find many examples here. I do not know what you mean by "keep running in the background", as timers do not run the background. — If you want to use Combine for this, take out the `autoconnect` and that way you can just call `connect` when it's time for the timer to start. I do not see in your code what your plan is for pausing.

Comment: I don't want the view to be connected directly to the timer. I want to use a view model. The timer must keep track of the start/end dates of the segment and every time it fires it must post the duration since start excluding any user pauses and including the background time as I've mentioned before. some other parts of the app could some times observe the timer too, not only the actual timer view and view model.

Comment: Sounds cool. However I still don't see why a timer publisher is needed for this. You can publish the subscribable info without also using a timer publisher.

Comment: When the user moves the app to the background the timer should stay running, I do this by cancel the publisher but saving the start date, and on foreground entering I create a new publisher and keep publishing, to the other parts of the app nothing has changed because they don't know the actual timer, they see only my wrapper "SegmentTimer"

Comment: What will actually calculate time other than the built in Timer class?

Comment: Built-in Timer class is certainly one way. I'm just saying you don't need to use a timer _publisher_. All you have to publish is the fact that the timer fired, which you can do with a Subject (or a Published, as you are doing). I certainly understand that you want to use Combine publisher-and-subscribe to separate the fact of the timer from the rest of the app. But you do not need to separate it from _yourself_. Hence my remark about two publishers.

Comment: First off, thanks for trying to help. when the user starts a time segment and then opens another app, my app goes to the background. I cancel the subscription on entering background. when the user switches to my app again it enters the foreground. I then create a new publisher and proceed. the view model that will use the segment timer shouldn't handle this stuff, it shouldn't care about stuff other than starting the timer, start date, received current elapsed time on each tick, calling pause/end and the segment end date. I'm open to different way if you have it.

Comment: I forgot to say that on entering foreground I calculate the the app was in the background and add it to the elapsed time so the user won't loose that duration just because the app was in the background. I then create a new time publisher and proceed.

Comment: Yes, that's the right way!

Comment: The retain cycle and memory leak you referred to caused by “.map(transform)”?

Comment: It's caused by the assign.

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: I don't know what more there is to say. See my discussion at https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/subscribers/subscribersassign.html

Comment: The segment timer class has an end() method which will cancel the subscription which in turn will release up stream. Is what I’m saying is valid or I’ve to use sink with weak self instead? Nice tip anyway.

Comment: Yes, I think that should release it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func testStart() {
        // Add expectation
        let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "tick")
        // Given
        let segmentTimer = SampleSegmentTimer()
        var elapsedTimes = [DateComponents?]()
        let elapsedTimeSub = segmentTimer.$elapsedTime.sink { elapsedTimes.append($0) }

        // When
        segmentTimer.start(tickEvery: 1) // I want to wait 3 seconds to let it tick 3 times

        // Add this line
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) { expectation.fulfill() }

        // Then
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5) // wait for the fulfillment signal
        XCTAssertEqual(elapsedTimes.count, 3)
}
```